# the R.S.S. First Step

Tags: phrase-meaning

On Tuesday at 8:12 am CDT, a Blue Origin New Shepard spacecraft launched a space capsule, **the R.S.S. First Step** and its crew on a suborbital jaunt that mimicked the same type of flight made by American astronaut Alan Shepherd 60 years ago. Among that crew was company founder Jeff Bezos, taking his own small step 21 years after getting his space company started.
Source: [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alexknapp/2021/07/20/jeff-bezos-successfully-launches-on-blue-origins-first-crewed-spaceflight/?sh=2fcb18514bd2)

What does RSS (the R.S.S. First Step) stand for? I googled and failed to catch it.

A wild guess I've got in mind is "Reusable Space Ship." Because the design of the spacecraft had reusability in mind. But it is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Reusable Space Ship"** according to [msn.com](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/blue-origins-1st-upgraded-new-shepard-spacecraft-for-astronauts-aces-launch-and-landing/ar-BB1cL8G4):

> *This test flight, the 14th overall for the New Shepard program, was a
> special one, featuring a booster and capsule that were both brand-new.
> (The previous mission, which flew in October 2020, involved a New
> Shepard vehicle that had already flown six times before.) Blue Origin
> named the new capsule the RSS First Step, **with RSS standing for
> "Reusable Space Ship**."*